# Merge git repo to existing repo on github

Tags: git, github

So I have a strange issue with git. I have a production site which is being updated through ftp but has no git repo. The git repo representing that site contains only a part of its sources and is on my local PC. Every time I edit a file I upload it with FTP to the production server and then commit the changes and push to github. I'm not running a local copy of the site, just the important sources that are being editted.

However I now want to create a git repo in the production folder on the server and then merge the repo (perhaps as a single commit) to the existing repo on github. How would I go about doing this without cloning? This way I can get rid of this terrible workflow and have the entire site version controlled and not just part of its sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new folder where i did a `git clone`. Then I copied all the files over from the old folder (it contained some config files which were ignored) and committed any files which needed to be committed. Now everything is version controlled.